# Configure GTK and Qt system fonts

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, lxde, awesome

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 with the Awesome window manager. Is there a set of programs where can I set system-wide fonts? In particular the monospaced font?

I can set the system-wide sans font for Qt using `qtconfig-qt4`.

I can set the system-wide sans font for GTK using `lxappearance` (this might affect Qt's font).

I can also set system-wide anti-aliasing and hinting using `lxappearance`.

However, how can I set the system-wide monospace font for Qt and GTK? Right now it is set to `Monospace 12` which is rendering huge.

I see so many methods and variations for changing font settings that I don't know which ways are remotely proper, and half of which are specific to a specific desktop environment (e.g.,  Gnome, KDE, Unity, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be working:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Noto Mono 11'`

(Probably not all apps, gedit changes instantly)

Comment: That looks pretty GNOME specific. Does that set the GTK font if you're not running GNOME?

Comment: Did not try it with anything else, but I guess only GNOME apps respect it.