# Make Roboto the default font

Tags: command-line, fonts

How can I change the default font in both Gnome and Terminal to [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) without installing any additional software? I'm using gnome-terminal.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454279/change-default-system-font-using-terminal-only-in-14-04/454292

Comment: Can you specify if you're trying to change Gnome fonts, or if you're trying to change fonts for your terminal?  If it's your terminal, can you specify which terminal you're using?

Answer (score 5):

I'm giving you a "change the font in Terminal, not system-wide monospace" response, since it seems what you are asking.

You need to install the font, then change the settings the Terminal.

1. `sudo apt-get install fonts-roboto`
2. Right click on Terminal
3. *Profiles* -> *Profile preferences*
4. Change the *Font:* to Roboto

Note: Roboto is not a monospace font, so it's not the best for use in Terminal. Your terminal use will be better with a monospace font such as [Inconsolata](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), DejaVu Sans Mono, Ubuntu Mono, or [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro).

Comment: FWIW, there's a very nice [mono version of Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono) that I've come to enjoy.  

(Ubuntu Mono tends to be my _usual_ go-to, though. Sometimes I switch it up out of boredom, but... that's not really important. ;))

Answer (score 0):

[I found this to be working](https://askubuntu.com/a/893194/266848):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Noto Mono 11'
```

(Probably not all apps, gedit changes instantly)